# Is it possible in MATLAB to create a 3D array from a function which returns 2D arrays without using a loop?

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, dictionary

I have a MATLAB function `f(w)` that returns a `(n x n)` square matrix. I have a vector `ws = [w_1, w_2, ... w_m]` which contains `m` parameters `w_i`. I would like to create a 3D array which contains the `m` "planes" `f(w_i)`. Is it possible in MATLAB using `arrayfun() et al.` to create this 3D array without using `for` loops to iterate over the parameter vector `ws` and concatenating the results?

Comment: `arrayfun` is not usually faster than a `for` loop. Ideally, you would make a vectorized version of `f`, which accepts `ws` and returns the 3D array. That may be possible or not, depending on what `f` does exactly

Comment: Sure, Luis, but this question was more aimed at improving my understanding of advanced MATLAB language features then achieving practical improvements in program execution time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to see how a few functions can be used, here's an approach where `arrayfun`, `cell2mat` and `reshape` are combined (I changed the last line according to Daniel's comment):

```
f = @(w) [w 2*w; 3*w 4*w];   %// Random function that returns an array of fixed size
w = 1:4;   %// Random input to function
out = cell2mat(reshape(arrayfun(@(x) f(w(x)), w, 'UniformOutput', 0),1,1,[]));
```

You could also do (probably fastest of these approaches, but there are probably even faster approaches):

```
out = f(reshape(w,1,1,[]))
```

Or use a loop like this (notice the order of the loop):

```
for ii = numel(w):-1:1
   out(:,:,ii) = f(w(ii));  %// No pre-allocation necessary
end
```

Or the more traditional loop approach:

```
out = zeros(2,2,4);   %// Pre-allocation necessary
for ii = 1:numel(w)
   out(:,:,ii) = f(w(ii));
end
```

I could go on, but I think you've have a few to look at here...

Comment: Hey thanks, I will definitely study your examples!
EDIT: Ah, your loop-without-preallocation trick is also really neat!!